# Installing android default sample code

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to install the default samples that come with the Android SDK. I am following the page http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html.

I do as mentioned in steps 1 and 2. But, I don't get the "Samples for SDK" option in the list. I wonder if I need to update something. I attach a screen shot of the place where I get stuck.

[image]

Thank you.

**EDIT**:
After I did an update to revision 20 as suggested by [Geeks On Hugs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315692/geeks-on-hugs), I was able to see *"Samples for SDK"* for each of the versions (pretty strange to me :/).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update to revision 20 and see if you see the samples. I've never seen the samples not available.  Try updating to revision 20 and if you still don't see them, I'd download version 20 directly.

Answer (score 1):

The samples are zipped and you have to undo each of them.  They should be in your tools folder under samples, unzip them, then follow the tutorial.  It helps when creating the project to use the include option on the sample folders if you don't unzip them to the workspace directory.